# Changing properties of a button via method from another class

Tags: c#, winforms

Maybe you can help me with my problem.

My Class "Form1" calls the method setButtons();

but setButtons() ist not at Class "Form1", its in Class "Class1".

setButtons() in "Class1" does not recognice Button1 from Form1.

How do I let it know that Button1 exists in Form1 and I want the method to work on the Button1 from "Form1"? Class1 has already a using directory to Form1 and Form1 has one to Class1.

```
//this does not work
public static void setbuttons()
{
    Form1.Button1.Location = new Point(40, 40);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out that if you declare a control public in the designer file like so

```
public Button button1;
```

Then you can access it from another class on the condition that you get the form object, for example as a extension

```
static class AnotherClass
{
    public static void setButtons(this Form1 form)
    {
        form.button1.Text = "Hello";
    }
}
```

A better way to change the properties of a button, in terms of design and code management, would be to make a method in your form that does it.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...
    }

    public void ChangeButtonTextMethod(string text)
    {
        button1.Text = text;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can do this, but it's not very good design. In general, allowing other classes, controls, forms, etc to manipulate the UI in this class leads to very tightly coupled code that is fragile. Rather than do this, I would expose a method on the form with the buttons that just takes a `string` parameter for the button text.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel yes that is what I would do as well. I proposed this method as the question specifically asks for a way to manipulate the control from an outside class. I will add that to the answer just in case.

Comment: Understood, but I would be wary of answering exactly what the OP asked, when it's not a good way to do it. Always better to suggest a more optimal approach.

Comment: Much better! Upvoted

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an event where the method in Class1 passes a Point to the calling form which listens for the event, in this case SetButtons.

```
public class Class1
{
    public delegate void OnSetLocation(Point point);
    public static event OnSetLocation SetButtonLocation;

    public static void SetButtons()
    {
        SetButtonLocation!(new Point(40, 40));
    }
}
```

In the form subscribe to SetButtonLocation, invoke the method SetButtons which passes a Point to the caller in Form1 and in turn sets the button Location.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Class1.SetButtonLocation += OnSetButtonLocation;
        Class1.SetButtons();
        Class1.SetButtonLocation -= OnSetButtonLocation;
    }

    private void OnSetButtonLocation(Point point)
    {
        button1.Location = point;
    }
}
```

Using this approach is better than changing the modifers of form to public as mentioned already.